# How to encode even permutations as integers

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, computational-mathematics

I consider even permutations of $n$ numbers. There are $n!/2$ even permutations.

I need to represent these permutations in a computer program as an integer between $0$ and $\frac{n!}{2} - 1$.

A theoretical procedure converting an even permutation into a number could enumerate all preceding permutations and count how many of them are even. But this procedure would be too slow for practical purposes.
Is there a faster procedure to encode and decode even permutations (possibly with different encoding) in this range ?

Comment: order them lexicographically

Comment: Heap's algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm)  generates a list of all permutations of $n$ by making one transposition at a time, so the lists thus generated alternate between even and odd permutations.  It might be possible to extract the $(2k)$th permutation (enumerating starting from 0) on the list without running through all the previous ones, and call that the $k$th even permutation. I can't see how to do it, though, which is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not hard to see that the lexicographical order of permutation $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-2} \frac{f_i(n-i)!}{2}$ where $f_i$ is the number of values that are smaller than $a_i$ and to the right of $a_i$.

using this formula we can clearly find the lexicographical order of a permutation in time $\mathcal O( n\log(n))$ .

You can also find the permutation with a certain value in time $\mathcal O(n\log(n))$ by going from left to right and selecting what value to insert ( use a data structure that allows you find the $k$'th smallest unused element). After selecting the first $n-2$ elements just order the final two so that the permutation is even.